# Misunderstanding over classes and definitions

Tags: python, class

I have been given these two class definitions:

```
class Weird(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y): 
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
    def getX(self):
        return x 
    def getY(self):
        return y

class Wild(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y): 
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
    def getX(self):
        return self.x 
    def getY(self):
        return self.y

X = 7
Y = 8
```

The first two questions were fine; they simply asked

```
w2 = Wild(X, Y)
print(w2.getX())
```

(which is 7) and

`print(w2.getY())`

What confuses me are the questions

```
w1 = Weird(X, Y)
print(w1.getX())
```

and

`print(w1.getY())`

both of whose answers are apparently "error", but I don't understand why this is the case. The errors given are "x is not defined" and "y is not defined" respectively, but I thought `x` and `y` are the parameters that we put into the function. What am I missing?

Comment: You wrote `return x`,  not `return self.x`.

Comment: `x` and `y` are locals in `Weird.__init__`. That means they don't exist *outside* of that function. `Weird.getX` and `Weird.getY` are separate functions with separate namespaces.

Comment: What's the difference between `x` and `self.x`?

Comment: `Wild` uses the `self` object (a reference to your current instance) to access attributes on that. That's how you share information between the different methods, they all share a `self` instance, which is passed in automatically for methods. `self.x` and `self.y` exist only because `__init__` set these.

Comment: @alexqwx: you want to look up what *attributes* are then. The obvious difference is the `self.` part there.

Comment: See [Why do you need "self." in Python to refer to instance variables?](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/303082)

Comment: Also https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/, and many other posts.

Comment: Last but not least, the Python tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first class, `x` and `y` are constructor arguments.
They are not accessible out of this scope.

In the `getX` function, `x` doesn't exists. You need to retrieve it from the `self` reference, such as in your second class.